# Why are birds have balls in the form a cork screw i dont have the scientific name

Tags: zoology

Why do birds have penises in the form of a cork  screw?

Comment: Please use a proper vocabulary. "balls" is a slang. Also, balls refer to the testicles, not to the penis.